# AFNetworking Reachability Show UIView When Network Status Changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, afnetworking-2, reachability

I am trying to implement ReachabilityManager in a project from AFNetworking 2.

I want to slide in a UIView when the status of the network changes.

The documentation for Reachability in AFNetworking 2.0 here: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/AFNetworking/2.4.1/Classes/AFNetworkReachabilityManager.html#//api/name/startMonitoring just points to code from Apple for their Reachability implementation example.  The Apple example does not seem to implement it as needed by AFNetworkReachabilityManager in AFNetworking 2.0.  I don't see an example anywhere in the documentation links provided in Git.

I have added the following to my viewWillAppear method:

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];
```

but what next? How do I check if the network status changes in my code so that I could then display a notice (in the form of a slide in UIView) to the user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to say what it should do when the reachability status changes. For example, from [the AFNetworking GitHub home page](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#network-reachability-manager):

```
[[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock:^(AFNetworkReachabilityStatus status) {
    NSLog(@"Reachability: %@", AFStringFromNetworkReachabilityStatus(status));
}];
```

If you want to show a view, you'd do it inside this `setReachabilityStatusChangeBlock`.

Comment: Wow. So much more simple than I thought it was going to be.